# React Native Input Field Placeholder not work in iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

> this is my code. android side is work fine but iOS not work.

```
applyLetterSpacing(string, count = 1) {
    return string.split('').join('\u200A'.repeat(count));
  }

<Item style={borderUnderLine}>
              <Input
                placeholder={this.applyLetterSpacing('NAME')}
                autoCapitalize='none'
                returnKeyType='next'
                onChangeText={(value) => this.setState({ name: value })}
                blurOnSubmit={false}
                style={{ letterSpacing: 2 }}
              />
            </Item>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use arrow function for applyLetterSpacing

```
applyLetterSpacing = (string, count = 1) => {
    return string.split('').join('\u200A'.repeat(count));
}
```

Comment: all app working in input field , no changes all app.